# .htaccess hacked? google returns internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error

I have been struggling with this for weeks, and would greatly appreciate any help. When I do a google search on my website, `http://www.example.com`, I get an internal server error. It took weeks but I finally got ahold of someone from google, and they said it wasn’t them, I needed to call godaddy. So I called godaddy, and they said I have a virus on my site, but for $300 they would clean it. I downloaded Wordfence and ran it, it cleaned up some items and says everything is now clear, but I’m still getting an internal server error.

I have pasted my htaccess file here
https://pastebin.com/NRDdFfZ0
and am wondering about the first three lines

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ maggoty-haroun.php?$1 [L]
```

I do have a php file called maggoty-haroun in my main site files, it just strikes me as an odd name.

https://pastebin.com/qnDu8f0k

We are a small restaurant, in a small town, badly hit by the pandemic and have been closed (curbside, delivery only) for months. Not being able to be found on google is going to be a killing blow. Is there anyone that can help?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I do have a php file called maggoty-haroun " - what does it do?

Comment: is it actively infecting people? it is our online menu...to lose the website would basically crush our business. could i delete it then put it back clean?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ maggoty-haroun.php?$1 [L]
> ```

You need to remove these directives.

These directives may simply result in a rewrite loop, hence your 500 internal server error, so they may not have done anything too malicious, except for making your site inaccessible (bad enough).

However, what they are trying to do... for any request that comes from a search engine crawler (`User-Agent`) OR from someone clicking on a result in the SERPs (`Referer`) then internally rewrite the request to `maggoty-haroun.php`, passing the requested URL-path in the query string (although due to the "rewrite-loop" they will end up just passing the same URL, ie. `maggoty-haroun.php`).

This can only be malicious - if it was successful it will de-index your pages in the search engines (and potentially damage your ranking by indexing "other" content) and prevent anyone from reaching your site.

However, unless your site is now "clean" you can't be sure that these directives won't be added back again - so you need to keep a close eye on it.

If these directives are simply resulting in a 500 error, then your site should bounce back (since a 500 error is considered "temporary" by search engines), providing this has not been the case for too long.

> I have pasted my htaccess file here ...

Wow, 4000+ lines of blocking user agents and IP addresses!?

Comment: That file is definitely malicious and should be deleted! (Just taking a look at it now, but it is extremely obfuscated!)

Comment: Yes, that is a malicious file as well and should be deleted. But how many more files? How many other files have been tampered with? And the problem isn't necessarily just these malicious files. How did they get there in the first place? It is that vulnerability that would need to be patched as well. Not wanting to be the bearer of bad news, but unless you are very familiar with a particular "hack", knowing how to manually fix it can be a monumental task. Recovering a known safe version from backup and reapplying updates may be the only way to reliably conquer this beast.